# Hapi.js views not loading css files

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js, hapi.js

I have an issue to link my `app.css` file to my `default.html` view using `hapijs` and `handlebars.js`. I use **Cloud9** for hosting.

Here is my app structure:

```
root/
   client/
      config/
         route.js
      css/
         app.css
      view/
         layout/
            default.html
         index.html
server.js
```

My `server.js`

```
'use strict';

const Hapi      = require('hapi');
const Vision    = require('vision');
const Inert     = require('inert');
const Path      = require('path');
const Routes    = require('./client/config/route')

const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    host: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000
});

server.register([Vision, Inert], (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.views({
        engines: {
            html: require('handlebars')
        },
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        path: 'views',
        layoutPath: 'views/layouts',
        layout: 'default', // true
        partialsPath: 'views/partials'
    });

    server.route(Routes);
});

server.start(() => {
    console.log('Server started at: ' + server.info.uri);
});
```

My `route.js`:

```
const Path  = require('path');

const routes = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: Path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                listing: false,
                index: false
            }
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: (req, rep) => {

            let data = { };                
            rep.view('index', data);
        }
    }
];

module.exports = routes;
```

My `default.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {{{content}}}
    </body>
</html>
```

My `index.html` :

```
<p id="paragraph"><p>
```

The issue is that my `app.css` doesn't load. I have followed [this advice](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1539) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852020/hapi-js-views-not-seeing-local-scripts?answertab=votes) but it still doesn't work and I don't know what to check next.

Comment: sorry I did not read the code very carefully

Answer (score 6):

You can write a separate route to serve your resources files

if `css` and `js` folder inside `resources` folder then

```
server.route({
path: "/resources/{path*}",
method: "GET",
handler: {
    directory: {
        path: "./resources",
        listing: false,
        index: false
    }
}});
```

this route will serve you static contents and then you can add these files in your html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css" />
```

for more ref check it 
http://jaskokoyn.com/2014/07/28/views-node-js-tutorial-beginners/

Answer (score -1):

as Gene Diaz told you:

put this right in your head section of default.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" link="your_file_name.css"/>
```